# Read from file and average total

Tags: python, list, exception, average

Python 3.x
Im trying to read from a file called numbers.txt. There are several rows of numbers in it. I need to print the total and average. Along with that I need to use exception handling for IOerror and ValueError.

Thank you in advance. I know there is a question like this but the suggestion errors out.

```
def main():
    total = 0.0
    length = 0.0
    average = 0.0
    try:
        filename = raw_input('Enter a file name: ')
        infile = open(filename, 'r')
        for line in infile:
            print (line.rstrip("\n"))
            amount = float(line.rstrip("\n"))
            total += amount
            length = length + 1
        average = total / length
        infile.close()
        print ('There were', length, 'numbers in the file.')
        print (format(average, ',.2f'))
    except IOError:
        print ('An error occurred trying to read the file.')
    except ValueError:
        print ('Non-numeric data found in the file')
    except:
        print('An error has occurred')
```

Comment: What do you have so far? Is this homework?

Comment: @user2330409 If it is homework, you should try something before asking. SO isn't a site to get your homework done, it's for help when you can't correctly debug something.

Comment: Thanks for the response and it is for homework, I just added it above. Well I have been trying for a while and it does need to be debugged. Sorry I didnt add the code in the post.

Comment: @user2330409 What error(s) do you get?

Comment: For my original code it just says an error has occurred as my ouput

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with open('numbers.txt', 'r') as my_file:
    try:
        data = [float(n) for n in my_file.read().split()]
    except (IOError, ValueError):
        data = []
total = sum(data)
average = total / len(data)
print('Numbers: {nums}\nTotal: {total}\nAverage: {average}'.format(nums = data, total = total, average = average))
```

For future reference, because this is fairly simple code, you can Google each part separately and you can piece them together.

Comment: Thanks and for the future I will use google but this is frustrating me. That code you gave me almost works but gives and error: 
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'

Comment: @user2330409 Check my edit (I forgot that reading a file returns a string).